# How to send gmail notification from google sheet at multiple column condition?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need email notification on gmail.

```
My file name is "PLC" 
Sheet name is "Sheet 1" 

Col A = "Names"
Col V = "Condition"
Col Y = "Condition"
Col X = "Emails"

Col A contains name of products,Col V contains conditions and Col X contains email address to notify. 

When Col V='Done', Col Y= 'Ready', It send notification to Col X.
```

Output
To: "email"
Subject: "Name" Pattern "Done"

message: Please Proceed for PPS for "Name" because Patten is "Done".

Thanks
[Google Sheet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xY25.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code -
An information will populate column Z when email has been sent.
You have to define a trigger on specialOnEdit function as following :
specialOnEdit / Head / From spreadSheet / On edit

```
function specialOnEdit(e){
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var cel = e.source.getActiveRange();
  if (sheet.getName()=='Sheet 1' && (cel.getColumn()==22 || cel.getColumn()==25)){
    var i = cel.getRow()
    if (sheet.getRange('V'+i).getValue()=='Done' && sheet.getRange('Y'+i).getValue()=='Ready' && sheet.getRange('Z'+i).getValue()!='EMAIL OK' ){
      GmailApp.sendEmail(sheet.getRange('X'+i).getValue(), sheet.getRange('A'+i).getValue(), 'Done') ;
      sheet.getRange('Z'+i).setValue('EMAIL OK')
      Browser.msgBox('Email sent')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it automatic when I select Done and Ready in the cell ?

Comment: I don't want to send emails to people who have already received it.

Comment: ok, put a special onEdit function (since onEdit doesn't admit sending emails) and put a information in a cell (hope column Z is free)